# ASP.NET FormView OnItemUpdate - not updated new values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have problem with event OnItemUpdate.. in dictionary NewValues are old values. What is wrong? How to get new values?

```
<asp:FormView
    runat="server"
    ID="frvKartaCharakterystyk"
    RenderOuterTable="false"
    DefaultMode="Edit"
    OnItemUpdating="frvKartaCharakterystyk_ItemUpdating">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="inputProdukt">Produkt</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="inputProdukt" CssClass="form-control" Text='<%# Bind("Produkt") %>' />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Update" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Zapisz</asp:LinkButton></div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"><asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" OnClick="Cancel_Click" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Anuluj</asp:LinkButton></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

My CodeBehind:

```
protected void frvKartaCharakterystyk_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.KartaCharakterystyk.Produkt = (string)e.NewValues["Produkt"];
            Response.Redirect("KartyCharakterystyk.aspx#record-" + (KartaCharakterystyk.Id - 1));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is no error message. Event fires correctly. The e.NewValues Dictionary stores old values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `Page_Load`:

```
this.frvKartaCharakterystyk.DataSource = new object[] { this.KartaCharakterystyk };
this.frvKartaCharakterystyk.DataBind();
```

Changed to:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    this.frvKartaCharakterystyk.DataSource = new object[] { this.KartaCharakterystyk };
    this.frvKartaCharakterystyk.DataBind();
}
```